# Acordar or recordar? What's the correct use? ¿Cuál es el uso correcto?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, verbos, gramática, conjugación

## Español

Comunmente escucho gente decir "*¿oye, te acuerdas de esa película?*", así como también escucho "*¿oye, recuerdas esa película?*."

Siempre he creído que la acción de un `recuerdo` viene del verbo `recordar`, entonces cuando alguien usa `acordar`, no me parece adecuado...

¿Qué piensan ustedes?

---

## English

Commonly I heard people saying "*¿oye, te acuerdas de esa película?*", the same way I heard "*¿oye, recuerdas esa película?*".

I've always believe that the action of `recuerdo` comes from `recordar`, so when someone uses `acordar`, it doesn't seem appropriated...

What do you guys think?

Comment: It's funny because I use to have pretty much the opposite issue: `recall` vs. `remember`.

Comment: LoL, didn't know this issue could apply on english...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is so small that people don't give too much care about which should be used. Also the use of each word is defined by been formal or informal (in some places)

- Acordar -> Agreement between two or more parts.
- Acordar -> Used instead of recordar / "no me puedo acordar donde puse
  mis cosas..."

There is also a new variant to these two used in some places

- Re-acordar -> Start to remember something again.

If used on the sense of "remembering" like in ¿oye, te acuerdas de esa película?, The question implies that both persons where together watching the movie, while ¿oye, recuerdas esa película? the person could had seen the movie at a different time (not with the person that ask the question). Although This is not a rule, and may not be correct in all countries.

Without been an expert I will say that personally, I will use one instead on the other depending on the case (formal or informal).

To answer your question correctly I will say that the use depends quite a lot on the region/country and unfortunately there in no rule that can be successfully applied to all countries (since the use of the word or meaning given in some countries may differ from the sense or meaning of the word given by others in other countries).

Answer (score 3):

Acordar also have an acception with the same meaning as recordar so both are correct.

From http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=acordar, the 6 acception:

acordar.
(Del lat. *accordāre, de cor, cordis, corazón).

1. Determinar o resolver de común acuerdo, o por mayoría de votos.
2. tr. Dicho de una sola persona: Determinar o resolver deliberadamente.
3. tr. Resolver, determinar algo antes de mandarlo.
4. tr. Conciliar, componer.
5. tr. Traer algo a la memoria de otra persona.

**6. tr. recordar (‖ traer a la memoria). U. m. c. prnl. Acordarse DE un hijo ausente**

1. tr. Mús. Disponer o templar, según arte, los instrumentos musicales o las voces para que no disuenen entre sí.
2. tr. Pint. Disponer armónicamente los tonos de un dibujo o de una pintura.
3. tr. ant. Hacer a alguien volver a su juicio.
4. intr. León, Bol., Hond. y Ur. caer en la cuenta.
5. intr. ant. Dicho de una cosa: Concordar, conformar, convenir con otra.
6. intr. ant. Dicho de una persona: Volver en su acuerdo o juicio. Era u. t. c. tr.
7. intr. ant. despertar (‖ del sueño). U. en Salamanca.
8. prnl. Ponerse de acuerdo.